# List Problem in python to sort a list of string without using sort or sorted function

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, data-science

I am stuck in this list problem, I am unable to solve it.

list1= ["aaditya-2", "rahul-9", "shubhangi-4"]

I need to sort this list without using sort/sorted function.... and also it should sort on the basis of numbers at the last..

Output:
["aaditya-2", "shubhangi-4", "rahul-9"]

OR

["rahul-9", "shubhangi-4", "aaditya-2"  ]

Comment: You need to implement a sorting algorithm. BubbleSort is generally regarded as the simplest. Take a look at some [common sorting algorithms](https://www.crio.do/blog/top-10-sorting-algorithms/). Another option since your list is small is to `random.shuffle()` it and check the order until it's correctly ordered. But really, it seems like the point of this problem is to implement a sorting algorithm rather than check random solutions.

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: To sort on the digits at the end, you can use `str.split("-")[-1]` to get just the number.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
def sort_arr(arr, function):
     arr2 = [function(i) for i in arr] # apply your function to all the elements in the array, in this case it is get the last digit
     for i in range(1, len(arr2)): # begin looping from the first index of the array to the last index
         k = arr2[i] # assign the value of the ith item to a variable
         j = i - 1 # keep track of the index begin considered
         while j >= 0 and k < arr2[j]: # while k is less than the item before it, do
                 arr2[j + 1] = arr2[j] # shift the ith value one step to the front of the array
                 j -= 1
         arr2[j + 1] = k # once the correct position has been found, position arr2[i] at its correct location
     return arr2 # return sorted array
print(sort_arr(list1, lambda x: int(x[-1]))) # the lambda gets the last digit and turns it into an integer
```

Learn more about lambda's [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp).

This is an implementation of insertion sort. Learn more about it [here.](https://realpython.com/sorting-algorithms-python/#the-insertion-sort-algorithm-in-python)

Hope this helps!

EDIT: Just realized this did not directly answer OP's question. Updated answer to match.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, it's a question of ordering. I don't think this is about implementing a sorting algorithm. Here I define a `order` function that works on two strings and orders them by last character. This is applied 3 times to sort 3-element list.

```
def order(a, b):
    return (b, a) if a[-1] > b[-1] else (a, b)
    
list1 = ["aaditya-2", "rahul-9", "shubhangi-4"]
a, b, c = list1

a, b = order(a, b)
a, c = order(a, c)
b, c = order(b, c)

list1 = [a, b, c] # ["aaditya-2", "shubhangi-4", "rahul-9"]
```

For reverse sort, just use `<` in the `order` function.